# Laravel 8: or middleware for route by auth:sanctum or auth.basic.once

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-sanctum

I'm wanting the user to be able to log in with the 2 auths that I create. But when i add like below it throws an error and it makes me enter both auth styles i created while i want to just enter one of the two auth styles to login successfully.

I don't know if anyone has had the same situation as me. And can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Code route api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

I have tried some ways as follows but it still doesn't work and that includes Middleware Parameters: **`https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters`**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum'|'auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

OR

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum|auth.basic.once']], function () {
   Route::get('/images', [ImageController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Comment: How is you intending the flow of this to work/why are you wanting to use both for this?

Comment: currently i am working on api. I want my stream to run like this when I use **auth:sanctum** then I pass the **bearer token** and I can only get the data. And when I use **auth.basic.once** under **Stateless HTTP Basic Authentication** of laravel then I can get `post`, `put`, `delete`, `get` data.

I don't know if you have tried this and is there a way to handle it ?